# How Can I Change the Icon on Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, shortcuts, icons, microsoft-outlook-2013

I would like to change the Icon for Outlook 2013.

When I right-click and select Properties, 'Change Icon' is greyed out.

As a supplementary question, how can I 'Run As Administrator'?  That option is greyed out too. Naturally, I am logged on as an Administrator.

[image: Shortcut Screenshot]

Extra Information
Current Workaround:
I went to the root file in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 15\Outlook.exe

> Right-Click 
>   Send to desktop, create shortcut.  Eureka, ‘Change Icon’ is available.
>
> Puzzle.  Pin to Taskbar – Problem as described above.
>
> More Puzzling: Pin to Menu – Eureka Change Icon button is alive.

To be clear, it’s Pin to Taskbar that causes the problem.

One more point, I get this behaviour on two machines, but both installed from same .iso file.

Comment: I checked my shortcut and I was able to change both the icon and set Outlook to always run as an administrator ( although thats not requuired and basically pointless ) sounds like you don't have the permissions on your user profile required to do either.

Comment: I checked on a second machine, same problem for me.  On both machines the user has Full Control on the security permissions tab.  Additional information, these were updates rather than fresh installs.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  I am not even logged in as an `Administrator` account and was able to change the shortcut to Outlook 2013.  The "Run As Administrator` is disabled for every shortcut I checked but checking on a computer where I was logged in as an `Administrator` I was able to do so.

Comment: I am now wondering if its possible to change the icon of ANY program pinned to the taskbar.

Comment: I selected a random shortcut on my desktop.  I opened up the program and pinned it to my taskbar.  I went to the shortcut and was able to change the icon for the shortcut.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for checking on your system.

Comment: I am able to change the icon for Windows Media Player on my taskbar, but not the one for Lync, Outlook, or Word.  This seems to be a problem with Office 2013.  Maybe it has something to do with the way the shortcut was created?  I notice the "Target" field does not have a valid path in it - it just says "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013".

Comment: I don't know which version of Windows you're on, but in Windows 7 (I'm using the Enterprise edition), there simply are no Run as Admin or Properties commands when you right click on a task bar icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you managed to sort the problem out but I might have a solution here.
I had the same problem: I couldn't change the icon because that option was greyed out.

I right clicked on the desktop and created a new shortcut, pointed it to Outlook and named it (just go through the prompts).

A new shortcut appeared on the desktop pointing to Outlook and I was able to go into that shortcut's properties and change the icon to whatever I wanted it to be (not greyed out anymore).
Afterwards I pinned that shortcut to the task bar and deleted it from the desktop.

Comment: Great, it worked.  I wonder if a service pack or patch increased the capabilities, or perhaps I missed it the first time around.  (And did not pay proper attention to Ramhound's comment).

Comment: This works for me too.  I believe that the reason there is a problem here is because Outlook changes the icon based on mail status.  It uses the change in icon to notify the user of new mail, probably among other things.  Once I set the icon to something else, this functionality is obviously lost.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note for all those that are curious, there is a program called windows enabler

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Windows-Enabler.shtml.

When you run it as administrator, you will be able to click on the grayed out buttons, and make them active, thus being able to (in this example) choose a different icon from the screen that was provided in the OP